# Cloud9 and MySQL, Connection Refused

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure this will be pretty easy, but I've been looking at this for a while, and haven't figured it out yet.
I've got a project in Cloud9 that I am trying to set up to access a MySQL database.
I've started the MySQL engine (mysql-ctl start), so I don't think that's the issue.

Here are my variables:

```
$db_hostname = "[username]-[projectname]-[assigned id]"; //this was retrieved by using 'SELECT @@hostname;' within MySQL
$db_database = "c9"; //default cloud9 database
$db_username = "[username]";
$db_password = ""; //the default is no password
$db_port = 3306; //the default cloud9 MySQL port
```

And here is my mysqli connect statement:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
```

And this is the error that is being sent back:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/insertWorkoutScript.php on line 11
>   Call Stack:
>   0.0009 248728 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/insertWorkoutScript.php:0
>   0.0012 249768 2.
>   mysqli_connect() /home/ubuntu/workspace/insertWorkoutScript.php:11
>   Connection failed: Connection refused

---

Line 11 (the line that the error identifies) is the `$conn = mysqli ...` statement.  I've verified that the variables are being filled (I've got an echo for each variable name and it's value).  I've double and triple checked the value I'm using for `$db_hostname` (which as I said, I retrieved from cloud9 using the `SELECT @@hostname;` statement).  And as I said, I've made sure to Start the MySQL instance with the `$ mysql-ctl start` line in the terminal.  Thoughts on what simple thing I'm missing here?
Thanks

Comment: I'm highly skeptical of your hostname. Running `SELECT @@hostname` in my environment shows `iMac.local` throws an error when I try to use it.

Comment: I definitely understand that skepticism.  And if I was running this locally, I would expect a different hostname.  I know when I've done things directly on my computer, I've used localhost.  But in this case, I'm doing this through Cloud9, so the host is different.  Here's the line from my Terminal.  mysql> select @@hostname;
+---------------------------+
| @@hostname                |
+---------------------------+
| [username]-[project name]-[7 digit id] |

Comment: I can see a mention of using `@@hostname` in the cloud9 docs now - but they also suggest using `getenv('IP');` as a way to get the IP address for the host name. [The docs I'm referencing.](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setting-up-mysql). If that works, out ill post it as an answer.

Comment: I've just tried using getenv('IP'), and I'm getting 0.0.0.0 back.  But I'm also no longer getting the Connection Refused error.  Now I'm getting an insertion error.  I suspect that is an issue with my SQL statement somewhere, that I will work to figure out.  Thanks for the getenv tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @HPierce for the reminder to try getenv('IP').  I had tried that earlier but got a bad function response.  My guess is that I typed it incorrectly, or was using it incorrectly.  I've tried that again, and am now getting a good connection.  So the correct settings are:

```
$db_hostname = getenv('IP'); // as opposed to using results from select @@hostname;
$db_database = "c9"; //default cloud9 database
$db_username = "[username]";
$db_password = ""; //the default is no password
$db_port = 3306; //the default cloud9 MySQL port
```

Everything else stayed the same.  And I've also now solved my SQL insertion error as well.
Thanks again for your help.